# Don't find use custom image option on Android Studio 2.0

Tags: image, android-studio

> How can i add Image Asset Image from computer?

On previous Android Studio has option to use custom Image in Image Asset but in new version i can't find that option.

> previous Android Studio Image Asset.

[image]

> new Android Studio 2.0 Image Asset.

[image]

Comment: Did you try copy and pasting it in the wanted folder? I always had that problem but helped it by just putting the images in the folders directly

Answer (score 1):

You just have to click on `Image` instead of `Clipart`

[image]